# Do a GET request with Arduino's Ciao library pointing to a non 80 port

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno-wifi

I'm trying to send a GET request to port 69 instead of 80, using the Arduino's Ciao library.

In the official documentation, found at http://www.arduino.org/learning/reference/ciao-rest, no one talks about requesting a port different than 80. Actually, it doesn't mention the word *port*, so... bad news there.

By the way, it seems that Ciao is the official way to work with the Arduino One Wifi, but if you know another way to do it, I will totally appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try adding it to the server address like `"192.168.1.1:69"`?

Comment: Yes: didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the port in REST Server Connector.

See http://www.arduino.org/learning/reference/ciao-restserver.

Comment: But the rest server connector is to receive data instead of requesting it to another server, isn't it? I mean, I'm trying to get data from a server on the internet.